# ASP.NET mvc remove item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I have simple Database

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Date] (
[Id]   INT        NOT NULL,
[Name] NCHAR (10) NULL,
[Date] DATE       NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

it contain two records

[image]

My application loading `Name` from database using `Date` and displaying it on screen. 
[image]

The main problem is that if i should remove one item from list using `Remove`
and than click on `Save data` button it should pass to `SaveData` nothing. 
I think that I have a serious architectural mistake because `SaveData` function do not know anything about record that need to be removed. How to fix it?

Index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<input type="text" value="02.01.2016">
<button data-bind="click: loadData">Load data</button>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
        <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeItems">Remove item</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button data-bind="click: saveData">Save data</button>
<script>
function MyViewModel(){
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray();
    self.removeItems = function (item) {
        self.items.remove(item);
    }
    self.loadData = function () {

        $.ajax({
            cache: false,

            type: "GET",

            url: "Home/GetData",

            data: { "date": $( "input" ).val() },

            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (id, item) {
                    self.items.push({ name: item.Name });
                });
            },

            error: function (response) {
                alert('eror');
            }
        });
    }
    self.saveData = function () {
        var jsonOfLog = JSON.stringify(self.items());
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'text',
            url: "Home/SaveData",
            data: "jsonOfLog=" + jsonOfLog,
            success: function (returnPayload) {
                console && console.log("request succeeded");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console && console.log("request failed");
            },

            processData: false,
            async: false
        });
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
```

HomeController:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    modelEntities ME = new modelEntities();
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetData(string date)
    {
        DateTime inputdate = DateTime.Parse(date);

        List<Date> list = ME.Date.Where(key => key.Date1 == inputdate).ToList();
        return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public string SaveData(string jsonOfLog)
    {

        return Convert.ToString(jsonOfLog);
    }
```

Comment: `it should pass to SaveData nothing` can you be more clear on this .

Comment: If SaveData is supposed to update a record, you probably want to use the `Id`

Answer (score 0):

```
var jsonOfLog = ko.toJSON({ jsonOfLog: self.items });

$.ajax({
  url:"Home/SaveData",
  data: jsonOfLog,
  type: "post",
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function(result) {
    alert(result)
  }
});
```